# ¿Cuál es el equivalente del múltiple selector de jQuery en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sintaxis

Tengo la intención de ir dejando jQuery y migrar a JS puro.

Este pequeño código sirve para cambiar un atributo title.

*jQuery:*

```
$('#id1, #id2').attr('title', 'Nuevo title');
```

**¿Cuál es el equivalente de este selector en JS?**

Intente con este sin el resultado esperado:

*JS:*

```
document.querySelector('#id1, #id2').title = 'Nuevo title';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función correcta a esar es `querySelectorAll` ya que este devuelve un `NodeList` (lista de nodos similares a un array) con todos los elementos seleccionados no solo el primero como hace `querySelector`

Luego de obtener el array de elementos debes iterar por cada uno para setear su atributo.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#id1, #id2")
  .forEach(function(e) {
    e.title = 'Nuevo title';
  });
```

```html
<span id="id1">Hola</span>
<br />
<span id="id2">Mundo</span>
```