# Como ejecutar doble evento con jquery

Tags: jquery

Como ejecuto dos eventos $(".ejemplo").click(function(){ en este query, es posible asignarle dos selectores para que ejecuten el mismo evento.

para ser mas exactos puedo ejecutar evento click para eliminardetalle y agregar.
que esten en un solo y no por separado

Normalmente jQuery asocia los eventos al terminar la carga de la página (el document.ready ).

Si creas elementos nuevos después de ejecutar el document.ready estos no tendrán los eventos asociados. Tendrás que asociarlos de nuevo.

por esa razon meti un oneclick dentro de otro por que el before agrega un html nuevo al dom. pero si los pongo por separado la variable que viene del before el evento de abajo no la agarra por que efectivamente cuando se inicia la pagina el dato no existe. como soluciono el problema gracias

me pueden dar un ejemplo

```
  $(".agregar").click(function(){



codigoproducto =$(this).parent().parent().children(".codigoproducto").html();

$(".agregarproducto").before(' <tr class="trjson"><th class="codigoproducto">'+codigoproducto+'</th></tr>');


$(".eliminardetalle").one('click', function() {

$(this).parent().parent().remove();
codigoproducto=$(this).parent().siblings(".codigoproducto").html();
console.log(codigoproducto);

});


});

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

      $(".agregar").click(function(){


///agregar carga variable
    codigoproducto =$(this).parent().parent().children(".codigoproducto").html();
///before la asigna al html
    $(".agregarproducto").before(' <tr class="trjson"><th class="codigoproducto">'+codigoproducto+'</th></tr>');


    $(".eliminardetalle").one('click', function() {
////recoge variable del html que fue asigando del before
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    codigoproducto=$(this).parent().siblings(".codigoproducto").html();
    console.log(codigoproducto);

    });


    });
```

Comment: deberias poner el codigo que llevas para que se te pueda ayudar

Comment: Hola Alberto,te saludo, recuerda que para que tus preguntas tengan éxito en el sitio y obtengas respuestas debes realizar correctamente las preguntas, revisa [ask].

Comment: podrías volver a redactar tu problema, es muy confuso

Comment: Creo que [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/94675/250) es la respuesta a tu problema.

Comment: la respuesta que busco es al seperar los eventos como hago para asociarlos???

Comment: Te escribí [una respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/134810/250) en otra pregunta explicándote que hacía falta eventos delegados para eso y te ponía un ejemplo de cómo se hacía ([en general](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/134810/250) y [para tu caso en particular](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/134756/por-qu%C3%A9-se-devuelve-varias-veces-un-valor-en-este-c%C3%B3digo/134762#comment251853_134810)). Y en la pregunta que enlazo se explica cómo asociar la misma cosa (un atributo, pero también funcionará con eventos) a varios elementos al mismo tiempo.

Comment: si Alvaro tambien te agradezco. Me di cuenta que ese era el error por que tu me dijiste.

Comment: ayer lo hice como me dijiste pero no se por que no me funciono. tal vez no actualice el script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Así:

```
$(".agregar,.otroselector,#yotromas").click(function(){
});
```

NOTA EDICIÓN: Releyendo lo que pides, creo que he contestado algo que no es, lo dejo de todas formas por si a caso si es lo que preguntas. En el otro caso, sería así:

```
$("body").on( "click", ".agregar", function() {
});
```

Con éste método, aunque el DOM esté cargado, mandará el evento al elemento del selector y te ahorras generar eventos dentro de eventos.

Comment: track3r si me funciono. Gracias. Llevo días con eso y solo era eso. Muchas gracias.